# How to Insert Different XML Field values into table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I Have an xml as mentioned below,

```
Declare  @Message as xml

set @Message='<message>

            <body>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <setup_time>10</setup_time>
            <prod_cycle_time>10</prod_cycle_time>
            <unit>cas</unit>
            <Flag>NULL</Flag>
            <FillingPO>NULL</FillingPO>
            <PackAtCAN1>NULL</PackAtCAN1>
            </body>
            </message>'
```

I'm trying to insert using below Query

```
INSERT into table(ID,Desc,Value)
  SELECT p.value('ID[1]','INT'),
         p.value('Desc[1]','NVARCHAR(50)'),
         p.value('Value[1]','NVARCHAR(40)')
  FROM  @message.nodes('/message/Body/') x(p)
```

I want to insert above XML data as mentioned below format

```
ID     Desc              Value
1      setup_time        10
1      prod_cycle_time   10
1      unit              Case
1      Flag              NULL
1      FillingPO         NULL
1      PackAtCAN1        NULL
```

But i'm able to insert only one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes, the first is to add a wildcard after `body/` in the nodes function to ensure all nodes are returned. Then in the select you `value('.', ...)` to get the value, and [local-name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx) to get the element name, so your query ends up like this:

```
  SELECT p.value('../../ID[1]','INT'),
         p.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(50)'),
         p.value('.','NVARCHAR(40)')
  FROM  @message.nodes('/message/body/*') x(p)
```

Comment: Above statement is working if <ID>1</ID> tag is above the <body> tag. But same thing is not working if <ID> tag is inside the <Body> tag.                                                   set @Message='<message>

            <body>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <setup_time>10</setup_time>
            <prod_cycle_time>10</prod_cycle_time>
            <unit>cas</unit>
            <Flag>NULL</Flag>
            <FillingPO>NULL</FillingPO>
            <PackAtCAN1>NULL</PackAtCAN1>
            </body>
            </message>'

Comment: If `ID` is in the body tag, then you just need to change where you are looking for it - e.g. `p.value('ID[1]','INT')`

Comment: Above statement is returning all xml tags and it's values in table format. But if i need few filed with values then how to do.xml fields like "setup_time,prod_cycle_time,unit" fields and it values.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Could you post a new question with your input and expected output please? Thanks